# Switch to another ViewController by selecting Cell of programmatically created collectionView

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I've got a CollectionView which was programmatically created, now I want to switch to another CollectionView by selecting one of its Cells. Heres my code so far, but nothing happens:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"Cell selected");
    DetailCell *detailCell = [[DetailCell alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailCell animated:YES];
 }
```

Console says "Cell selected", so the CollectionView recognizes my touch, but the app won't switch to the other view. I've created a ViewController with the custom Class "DetailCell".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem :

mainView .m

```
cView = [[CollectionView alloc]init];
cView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 436);
cView.nav = self.navigationController;
[_contentScrollView addSubview:cView.view];
```

CollectionView.h

```
@property (nonatomic,weak)  UINavigationController *nav;
```

CollectionView.m

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

    DetailCell *detailCell = [[DetailCell alloc] initWithDetails:_pageCategorie and: indexPath];
    [_nav pushViewController:detailCell animated:YES];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check and make sure your self.navigationController isn't nil.

Comment: Ok I checked it, it is nil, how do I change it/how to add it to the navigationController ? My collectionView is created inside a Scrollview, which is in the Root View Controller of a Navigation Controller

Comment: Why are you putting a UICollectionView inside a UIScrollView? UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView. I'd check out one of the many tutorials online on how to use collection views. From what I can tell, you are having issues because you aren't using collection views as intended.

Comment: It's a horizontal scrollview, I'm putting many collectionviews next to each other.